# Understanding proof of unique factorization of polynomial in Linear Algebra Done Right

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I am reading "Linear Algebra Done Right". Right now I am stuck with the uniqueness part of Corollary 4.8, Existence and Uniqueness polynomial factorisation in the form of $p(z) = c(z-\lambda_1)(z-\lambda_2)...(z-\lambda_m)$.

It is stated that if there are two factorisations of $p$, $(z-\lambda_1)(z-\lambda_2)...(z-\lambda_m) =(z-\tau_1)(z-\tau_2)...(z-\tau_m)$. We can divide both sides by $(z-\lambda_1)$ as one of the $\tau$ must equal $\lambda_1$.

Here comes the confusing part for me: After division, we get $(z-\lambda_2)...(z-\lambda_m) = (z-\tau_2)...(z-\tau_m)$ for all $z \in C$ except for possibly $z=\lambda_1$. **Actually the equation above must hold for all $z \in C$ because otherwise by subtracting the right side from the left side we would get a nonzero polynomial that has infinitely many roots.**

I understand a finite polynomial can't have infinitely many roots, but need elaboration on bolded part, like why it suddenly(?) holds for $z=\lambda_1$, and how comes the theoretical nonzero polynomial has infinitely many roots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what it means is:  You start with  $(z-\lambda_2)\cdots(z-\lambda_m)=(z-\tau_2)\cdots(z-\tau_m)$ at every point except $z=\lambda_1$.  This means the polynomial $(z-\lambda_2)\cdots(z-\lambda_m)-(z-\tau_2)\cdots(z-\tau_m)=0$ at every point except $z=\lambda_1$ (infinitely many roots) yet it is nonzero (we assumed the two sides aren't equal for $z=\lambda_1$).  This is a contradiction, thus the two sides must be equal even when $z=\lambda_1$.