# Proof of unique factorization of polynomial over $\mathbb{C}$ in Linear Algebra Done Right.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, proof-explanation

The following theorem appears in *Linear Algebra Done Right*

> If $p\in P(\mathbb{C})$ is a nonconstant polynomial, then $p$ has a
> unique factorization (except for the order of the factors) of the form
>
> $$p(z)=c(z-\lambda_1)...(z-\lambda_m)\tag{1}$$
>
> where $c,\lambda_1,...,\lambda_m\in\mathbb{C}$.

This [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2227239/understanding-proof-of-unique-factorization-of-polynomial-in-linear-algebra-done) investigates a specific step in the proof.

Here is the proof as it appears in Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right* with my comments and questions interspersed.

**Proof**

> Let $p\in P(\mathbb{C})$ and let $m=\text{deg}(p)$. We will use
> induction on $m$.
>
> If $m=1$, then clearly the desired factorization exists and is unique.

We have $p(z)=az+b=a\left (z-\left (-\frac{b}{a}\right )\right )$ where $\lambda_1=-\frac{b}{a}$ is the root.

Clearly the factorization exists, but how do we know this is unique?

We know that a polynomial of degree 1 has at most one root, so there are no other roots. Furthermore, we know that we can write $p(z)$ as $(z-\lambda_1)q(z)$ where $q$ has degree 0. In our case, $q(z)=a$.

Suppose there were some other factorization $(z-\lambda_1)r(z)$ where $r(z)=c$ with $c$ a constant.

Then, $(z-\lambda_1)a=(z-\lambda_1)c$ and so $a=c$.

Thus, the factorization is unique.

> So assume that $m>1$ and that the desired factorization exists and is
> unique for all polynomials of degree $m-1$.
>
> First we will show that the desired factorization of $p$ exists. By
> the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, $p$ has a zero $\lambda$. By
> Theorem 4.11, there is a polynomial $q$ such that
>
> $$p(z)=(z-\lambda)q(z)\tag{2}$$
>
> for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$.
>
> Because $\text{deg}(q)=m-1$, our induction hypothesis implies that $q$
> has the desired factorization, which when plugged into the equation
> above gives the desired factorization of $p$.

Now we get to the part that I have questions about.

> Now we turn to the question of uniqueness.
>
> Clearly $c$ is uniquely determined as the coefficient of $z^m$ in $p$.

The proof of this statement seems to use the same argument I used above for the case of a linear function. We suppose that we have two different factorizations

$$p(z)=c_1(z-\lambda_1)...(z-\lambda_m)\tag{3}$$
$$p(z)=c_2(z-\lambda_1)...(z-\lambda_m)\tag{4}$$

and when we equate them we see that it must be that $c_1=c_2$. Thus, $c$ is unique in this type of factorization $p$.

> So we need only show that except for the order, there is only one way
> to choose $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_m$.

Since we have a unique constant, and the rest of the polynomial is a product of $m$ factors that each represent a root, and since a polynomial has at most as many zeros as its degree, and the degree of $p$ is $m$, then why can we not directly conclude that this is the only way to "choose $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_m$?

Why do we need to suppose that we can write the factors with different roots as is done below?

> If
>
> $$(z-\lambda_1)...(z-\lambda_m)=(z-\tau_1)...(z-\tau_m)\tag{5}$$
>
> for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$, then because the left side fo the equation
> above equals $0$ when $z=\lambda_1$, one of the $\tau$'s on the right
> side equals $\lambda_1$. Relabeling, we can assume that
> $\tau_1=\lambda_1$.
>
> Now for $z\neq \lambda_1$, we can divide both sides of the equation above by $z-\lambda_1$, getting
>
> $$(z-\lambda_2)...(z-\lambda_m)=(z-\tau_2)...(z-\tau_m)\tag{6}$$
>
> for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ except possibly at $z=\lambda_1$.
>
> Actually, the equation above holds for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$, because otherwise by > > > subtracting the right side from the left we would get a nonzero polynomial that has infinitely many zeros.

I wa stumped on this lat paragraph, but this [other question explains it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2227239/understanding-proof-of-unique-factorization-of-polynomial-in-linear-algebra-done).

> The equation above (6) and our induction hypothesis imply that except
> for the order, the $\lambda$'s are the same as the $\tau$'s,
> completing the proof of uniqueness.

I am also not sure about this conclusion to the proof.

Does he just repeat the same argument used for $\lambda_1$ again $m-1$ times to reach the conclusion that $\lambda_i=\tau_i$ for $i=1,...,m$?

Comment: The reason we need to "suppose that we can write the factors with different roots" is because the roots $\lambda_i$ are not necessarily unique. For the argument you are suggesting, we would require the roots to be unique. The answer below addresses this implicitly, but I just wanted to make it explicit for you.

Comment: So we have a factorization (found in the existence portion of the proof), with $m$ factors of form $(x-\lambda_i)$. The $\lambda_i$'s don't have to be distinct. Thus, we may actually have strictly less than $m$ distinct roots. If the $\lambda_i$'s were distinct, then it would not be possible to have a second factorization with a root not present in the first factorization. Thus, the $m$ factors would necessarily have to be the ones present in the first factorization. But since the $\lambda_i$'s are not necessarily distinct, then

Comment: (and here I am wondering), (i) perhaps a second factorization could have some new root not present in the first factorization? I am trying to figure out what is left unproved by not going through the portion of the proof starting at (5).

Comment: As you say in (i), without doing any work, we do not know if there does or does not exist a second factorisation with some new roots. If you include your argument for the case of distinct roots, then you still need to consider the case of indistinct roots which is what the portion of the proof starting at (5) takes care of. However, this argument takes care of both cases so there is no need to consider separate cases.

Comment: Does the following argument work instead of the argument starting at (5)? Suppose a second factorization does contain a factor representing a root $\tau$ not contained (as a factor $z-\lambda$) in the first factorization. Then we would still need to have $p(\tau)=c(\tau-\lambda_1)...(\tau-\lambda_m)=0$ and since $\tau$ is different from the $\lambda$'s then this expression is definitely not zero, which is a contradiction. Therefore, the roots in the second factorization are the same as those in the first factorization. I feel like at this point there is still something unproved though.

Comment: The second factorization has to have the specific form we chose ($m$ factors of form $z-\tau$), but some can be repeated. So I guess it would be possible for the roots to be the same but somehow with different powers?

Comment: I think your argument works. To prove that the powers are the same you can simply argue divisibility of the polynomials. Say in one factorisation of $p(z)$, the factor $(z-a_1)$ has multiplicity $n_1$ and in another, it has multiplicity $m_1$. Then, both $(z-a_1)^{n_1}$ and $(z-a_1)^{m_1}$ divide $p(z)$. It follows that $n_1 = m_1$. Although writing this in detail would probably be longer than the induction argument.

Answer (score 4):

First, note that the proof consists of two parts: an *Existence* part, and then a *Uniqueness* part.

We prove *Existence* by induction on the degree. There is no need to prove uniqueness in that argument, and there is no assertion of uniqueness in that argument. Axler does it because he will also prove uniqueness by induction and so he is doing the base case for both parts here.

Second: in the *Uniqueness* clause of the proof, we *also* use induction on $m$. We have already proven it for $m=1$ (along the way, but we could have waited until here to prove it).

Now assume that any two factorizations of a polynomial of degree $m=1$ are identical up to order. And we prove the same is true for a polynomial of degree $m$.

Note that there is *no* assumption that all the roots are distinct. That is, when you write
$$(z-\lambda_1)\cdots (z-\lambda_m) = (z-\tau_1)\cdots(z-\tau_m),$$
we do *not* assume that if $i\neq j$ then $\lambda_i\neq \lambda_j$, nor that $\tau_i\neq\tau_j$. We do know setting $z=\lambda_1$ gives $0$ on the left, and hence *at least one* of the factors $(\lambda_1-\tau_i)$ must equal zero. There could be more, but we don't care. As long as there is *one* that equals zero, which there is, we relabel so that it is $i=1$.

At this point, we have
$$(z-\lambda_1)(z-\lambda_2)\cdots (z-\lambda_m) = (z-\lambda_1)(z-\tau_2)\cdots (c-\tau_m).$$
If you plug in any value of $z$ different from $\lambda_1$, then the factors $z-\lambda_1$ on both sides are nonzero and can be cancelled, so you get that
$$(z-\lambda_2)\cdots (z-\lambda_m) = (z-\tau_2)\cdots(c-\tau_m),$$
for all $z$ except perhaps $z=\lambda_1$. There is no assumption that none of the $\lambda_i$ or $\tau_j$ remaining are different from $\lambda_1$.

So now we have a polynomial of degree $m-1$, namely
$$(z-\lambda_2)\cdots(z-\lambda_m),$$
and we have two factorizations of it,
$$(z-\lambda_2)\cdots(z-\lambda_m) = (z-\tau_2)\cdots (c-\tau_m).$$
We don't need to "repeat the same argument": we invoke the *Induction Hypothesis.* It says that these factorizations are identical except perhaps for the order of the factors. So we know that we can reorder the $\tau_j$ so that $\lambda_2=\tau_2$, $\lambda_3=\tau_3,\ldots,\lambda_m=\tau_m$.

Putting it together with the fact that up to reordering we already had $\lambda_1=\tau_1$, we get the uniqueness of the factorization.

Comment: Just to try to be very clear about what uniqueness means in this theorem. For a polynomial $p$, we know the factorization of the specific form we are interested in exists (shown by induction on the degree of the polynomial). For such a factorization of $p$ in this specific form to be unique, it means that the set of factors is always the same. To prove this, we showed first that the constant must be the same, and then we used an induction argument to prove that the other factors must also always be the same.

Comment: @evianpring: It is proven directly that for degree $1$ polynomials any "two" factorizations are identical. Then it is proven by induction that for degree $m\geq 1$, any two factorizations are identical except perhaps for the order of the linear factors that are of the form $z-\lambda$ for some complex number $\lambda$.